# OS X: write syscall is not executed when loading binary to memory

Tags: c, macos, assembly, system-calls

I have a simple hello world program written in assembly. It prints "Hello, world!" and exits. When compiling with `nasm` and executing the code directly, everything works fine.

I also wrote some C code to load a flat binary and execute its code using `mmap`.  When loading the flat binary, the text is not printed out.  I'm pretty sure the call is happening, because adding an extra call to `exit` causes the program to exit prematurely.  Here's the code for the assembly program:

```
   global start

   section .text
start:
; write is not run
   mov   rax, 0x2000004
   mov   rdi, 1
   mov   rsi, msg
   mov   rdx, msg.len
   syscall

; but exit is...
   mov   rax, 0x2000001
   mov   rdi, 0
   syscall

   section .data
msg:    db      "Hello, world!", 10
.len:   equ     $ - msg
```

Compile it with `nasm -f macho64 hello.s && ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 hello.o -o hello` and generate a flat binary with `objcopy -O binary hello.o hello.bin`.

The code to load and execute the binary looks like this:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* allocate executable memory size-bytes long */
void* memexec_alloc(size_t size)
{
    void* ptr = mmap(0, size,
                     PROT_READ   | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                     MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON,
                     -1, 0);
    if (ptr == (void *)-1) {
        printf("mmap error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return ptr;
}

/* Load contents of file f into mem */
void memload(const char *f, unsigned char *mem)
{
    FILE *file;
    size_t size;
    unsigned char *data;

    file = fopen(f, "r");

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    data = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    fread(data, sizeof(char), size, file);
    fclose(file);

    memcpy(mem, data, sizeof(char) * size);
    free(data);
}

static const size_t SIZE = 1024;
typedef void (*voidfunc)(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        puts("no file specified!");
        return 1;
    }
    void *mem = memexec_alloc(SIZE);
    memload(argv[1], mem);

    voidfunc func = mem;
    func();
    return 1;
}
```

Inspecting the code in a debugger shows that the first `syscall` *is indeed* executed, but nothing is printed out, the program then exits with a value of 0 instead of 1. How do I get it to print?

(The OS is OS X Mavericks, 64 bit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of debugging and research, it seems I've got it. The loading of the value of `msg` is done with `mov   rsi, msg`. This uses an absolute address, which has no meaning when inside the C program (the loader). The loader's addresses are completely different, and the location of `msg` is also different. Thus, we need to load the address with `lea   rsi, [rel msg]`. This will give us the relative address of `msg`. We're still missing something though. Compiling `hello.bin` using the command from before won't work, because relative addressing is decided at link time, thus, we need to link `hello.o` first:

```
   global start

   section .text
start:
   mov   rax, 0x2000004
   mov   rdi, 1
   lea   rsi, [rel msg]
   mov   rdx, msg.len
   syscall
; added a `ret' so we return to the loader
   ret

   section .data
msg:    db      "Hello, world!", 10
.len:   equ     $ - msg
```

Compile with:

```
$ nasm -f macho64 hello.s
$ ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 hello.o -o hello
$ objcopy -O binary hello hello.bin
```

And it should result in a `hello.bin` that runs properly.